# Time conversion issue from varchar to time without date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, sql-server-2008-r2

**This Query works as expected**

```
SELECT CAST('8:40 AM' AS TIME) Times
UNION
SELECT CAST('12:01 PM' AS TIME)
UNION
SELECT CAST('12:04 PM' AS TIME)
UNION
SELECT CAST('12:41 PM' AS TIME)
UNION
SELECT CAST('12:45 PM' AS TIME)
UNION
SELECT CAST('1:28 PM' AS TIME)
UNION
SELECT CAST('1:43 PM' AS TIME)
```

**OUTPUT FOR ABOVE SELECT QUERY**

```
Times
----------------
08:40:00.0000000
12:01:00.0000000
12:04:00.0000000
12:41:00.0000000
12:45:00.0000000
13:28:00.0000000
13:43:00.0000000
```

**This Query also works as expected**

```
DECLARE @timeString VARCHAR(MAX) =
'
8:40 AM ,
12:01 PM,
12:04 PM,
12:41 PM,
12:45 PM,
1:28 PM ,
1:43 PM,,
'

;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TIMELIST.a.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') Times FROM(SELECT CAST('<P>'+REPLACE(@timeString,',','</P><P>')+'</P>' AS XML) AS TIMESPLIT) AS T CROSS APPLY  T.TIMESPLIT.nodes('/P') AS TIMELIST(a)
)
SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Times)) Times FROM CTE WHERE Times != ''
```

**OUTPUT FOR ABOVE SELECT QUERY**

```
Times
------------
8:40 AM
12:01 PM
12:04 PM
12:41 PM
12:45 PM
1:28 PM
1:43 PM
```

**This Query is not working as expected**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TIMELIST.a.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') Times FROM(SELECT CAST('<P>'+REPLACE(@timeString,',','</P><P>')+'</P>' AS XML) AS TIMESPLIT) AS T CROSS APPLY  T.TIMESPLIT.nodes('/P') AS TIMELIST(a)
)
SELECT CAST(LTRIM(RTRIM(Times)) AS TIME) Times FROM CTE WHERE Times != ''
```

**The above query returns the error.**

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 83 Conversion failed when converting
>   date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64)   Jun 17 2011 00:54:03   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

Comment: Oh... stick with CAST AS XML hack then!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "string" values contain newline characters (CR and LF). LTRIM/RTRIM do not trim those characters so you need to:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TIMELIST.a.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') Times
    FROM (
         SELECT CAST('<P>'+REPLACE(@timeString,',','</P><P>')+'</P>' AS XML) AS TIMESPLIT
    ) AS T
    CROSS APPLY T.TIMESPLIT.nodes('/P') AS TIMELIST(a)
)
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(TIMES)), CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), '') AS VARCHAR) Times
FROM CTE WHERE Times!=''
```

If you're using SQL 2016+ then `STRING_SPLIT` is a far more elegant solution. If you're using 2017+ then `TRIM(... FROM ...)` simplifies the trimming.